# How is it possible to have bio longer than 160 chars in Twitter

Tags: twitter

Take a look at @syldatk20 on Twitter (The profile has since been suspended so visiting the page will return a 404 error).

This guy's Bio is really, really long. He bypassed Twitter's character limit, but I have no idea how.

The only weird thing I see there is the double space before 160th char. I think there is some special character (CESU-8?), but Twitter just doesn't display it.

Comment: The profile you referred to is suspended.

Comment: Shows that the original person hacked Twitter just to do that, and was banned.

Comment: I've seen tweets bypass the 140 char mark...

Comment: Anyways, did you get a character dump of it all, or are you assuming those characters are there? It would help to have a Unicode dump of the string? As in char numbers of each one...

Comment: @Hydra off topic: Twitter really should state why they were banned (especially to the user themselves)...